# Rules component parameter form: choose node from drop down list

Tags: 7, rules

I create new rules component with parameter of type Node. In the form it provides the textfield input to enter the Node ID.

Is there any way to make a drop down nodes list instead to choose one?

Is there any way to put a view in that form to choose parameters via VBO?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without hook_form_alter?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `hook_form_alter` but will need to change the form element type to select or autocomplete.